# get a subset of edge labels in igraph plot

Tags: r, igraph

Given the following `data.frame`:

```
df <- structure(list(POP1 = c("ES13-15", "ES13-15", "ES16-18", "ES16-18", 
"ES19-21", "ES19-21", "ES22-24", "ES22-24", "ES25-27", "ES25-27", 
"ES28-30", "ES28-30", "ES31-33", "ES31-33", "ES34-36", "ES34-36", 
"ES37-38", "SA1-3", "SA4-6", "SA7-9", "SA10-12", "SA13-15", "SA16-18", 
"SA19-21"), POP2 = c("SA1-3", "ES16-18", "SA1-3", "ES19-21", 
"SA4-6", "ES22-24", "SA7-9", "ES25-27", "ES28-30", "SA10-12", 
"SA13-15", "ES31-33", "SA16-18", "ES34-36", "SA19-21", "ES37-38", 
"SA22-25", "SA4-6", "SA7-9", "SA10-12", "SA13-15", "SA16-18", 
"SA19-21", "SA22-25"), FST = c(0.0129, 0.0109, 0.0176, 0.012, 
 0.0564, 0.0275, 0.0193, 0.0108, 0.029, 0.0416, 0.0398, 0.0061, 
 0.0541, 0.0134, 0.0402, 0.0205, 0.024, 0.0081, 0.0035, 0.02, 
 0.0094, 0.0095, 0.0161, 0.0199)), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = 
 "data.frame")
```

A print snippet of the df looks like that :

```
POP1    POP2    FST
ES13-15   SA1-3 0.0129
ES13-15 ES16-18 0.0109
ES16-18   SA1-3 0.0176
ES16-18 ES19-21 0.0120
ES19-21   SA4-6 0.0564
ES19-21 ES22-24 0.0275
ES22-24   SA7-9 0.0193
ES22-24 ES25-27 0.0108
ES25-27 ES28-30 0.0290
```

And this is the code for my graph:

```
 g3 <- graph_from_data_frame(d = df3[,c(1,2)],directed = F)

 E(g3)$weight = df3$FST

 plot(g3,
 vertex.color=ColMap,
 vertex.frame.color="white",
 vertex.label.color="black",
 vertex.label.cex = .6,
 layout=layout.auto(g3),
 edge.label = E(g3)$weight,
 edge.label.cex = 0.6)
```

The weight attribute vector is the following one:

```
E(g3)$weight <- c(0.0129, 0.0109, 0.0176, 0.012, 0.0564, 0.0275, 0.0193, 
0.0108, 0.029, 0.0416, 0.0398, 0.0061, 0.0541, 0.0134, 0.0402, 0.0205, 
0.024, 0.0081, 0.0035, 0.02, 0.0094, 0.0095, 0.0161, 0.0199)
```

My graph without the weight attribute vector looks almost the way I would like to have.[image]

My only issue is when I give `edge.label = E(g3)$weight` command I get all the numbers for every edge of the graph, however I would like to have only the values of the edges that are in between different colors (purple and green).

I tried to exclude some indices of the weight vector like this : `E(g3)$weight[c(-4,-6,-8,-9,-12,-14,-16,-18:-24)]` as those indices are not the ones I want , but it did not work.

Is there a way to get printed on the graph only some of the `edge.label` and hide the others ???

Comment: Just a guess, maybe set the labels you don't want to `NA`?

Comment: Your code throws an error: `Error in i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(...)) : 
  object 'ColMap' not found`.

Comment: Or set the labels you don't want to `""`?

Comment: The `NA` trick worked with me.

Comment: sorry, `ColMap = rep('seagreen3',vcount(g3))`
`ColMap[grep('^SA',V(g3)$name)] = 'plum3'`

Comment: I managed by using `NA` however my graph layout changed and I no longer can recover the graph above. How can I recover the graph above with the `edge.labels` in place ???

Comment: The way your graph looks is random, so you should find a seed giving a graph you like.